# aws-sdk send request with IAM Auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, request, token, amazon-iam

I would like to make my Lambda function comunicate with a API Gateway...

However what I want is that the API Gateway checks the request with `AWS_IAM`... therefore the lambda function should in some way "sign" the request with a specific IAM token i suppose...

I was reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html, but I'm not able to find any example on how to sign the request with a specific IAM User

(I've already created a User in IAM with `AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess` and I have both access key and secret key, so I suppose I really need only the "how to sign the request")

Comment: The process depends on your programming language. THe easiest one, I know of at least, is in python, as there packages for that already. Also, you can't use aws-sdk for that. It must be third-party.

Comment: @Marcin i would like to use NodeJS if it’s possible (but I genuinely thouth there was sone SDK from AWS that does this automatically)

Comment: The SDKs are for management of API, not for making regular end-user requests to it. For nodejs there is [this](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) package. Have you considered it?

Answer (score 0):

We need to build regular nodejs request options with three additional parameters

`service: "execute-api"` for Api Gateway

`region: "us-east-1"` AWS Region.

`body: postData` , typically we pass body  `req.write`, we also need it in options because it is needed for signing.

and finally the `aws4.sign(...)` is passed to `request`.

All `.sign` method does is adds 4 additional headers `X-Amz-Content-Sha256`, `X-Amz-Security-Token`, `X-Amz-Date` and `Authorization`

```
var aws4 = require("aws4");
var https = require("https");

const requestBody = { name: "test" };
var postData = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  hostname: "abcdefgh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  path: "/qa",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  service: "execute-api",
  region: "us-east-1",
  body: postData,
  maxRedirects: 20,
};

const signedRequest = aws4.sign(options, {
  secretAccessKey: "abcadefghijknlmnopstabcadefghijknlmnopst",
  accessKeyId: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST",
  sessionToken: "this is optional ==",
});
console.log(signedRequest);
var req = https.request(signedRequest, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

since this call is made from lambda whole object with keys can be skipped and simply call `aws4.sign(options)`, it should use from environment variables.